# Need advice on RAII design for object/connection pool items

Tags: c++, raii

I'll open by saying I've been looking into this for a few days, trying to grok what is the "right way" of doing it. After plenty of googling on RAII/pool design/smart pointers, and having come to no definite conclusion (except that maybe there is no absolute "right way"), I thought maybe it's time for someone more knowledgeable to point me in the right direction.

I'm building an object pool, and I'm trying to make sure the client code can use RAII, if desired.

There are 3 entities involved:

- Resource. Expensive to build, semi-cheap to reuse (checking its state on release is not trivial). Difficult to copy, as it wraps some C constructs, with their own allocated memory/resources.
- Wrapper/Handle. Wrapper for the Resource. Is given a Resource on ctor, releases it on dtor.
- Controller/Pool. Maintains a pool of Resources and manages their use by clients, via Wrapper or, at the client's discretion, directly.

I present below a simplified example of what I've come up with. In the function `DoSomethingElse()`, you can see what I'm after - I get a reference to a Wrapper and, at the end of the scope, its dtor is invoked, and the Resource is released back to the pool.

My question has to do with the definition of `Factory::GetResource()`. The simplified version presented here just allocates a new one every time; my actual implementation checks the pool for an available Resource (creates one if there's none available), marks it as in use, and returns a reference to it.

I'd rather avoid having to define a proper copy ctor for the Resource, hence the return by reference, instead of by value. The Resource is guaranteed to outlive the caller, and the Controller maintains ownership throughout the app's life - they're not handed to the client code for life-cycle management. Of course, if the client asks for a direct reference, i.e., without the Wrapper, all bets are off.

Is this design sound? Would I be better off using shared_ptr? Or some other mechanism/design?

Thanks for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static int seq = 0; // POOR MAN'S SEQUENCE FOR INSTANCE IDs

class Resource
{
public:
    Resource() : id(seq++) { cout << "Resource ctor: " << id << endl; }
    ~Resource() { cout << "Resource dtor: " << id << endl; }
private:
    int id;
};

class Wrapper
{
public:
    // ON ACTUAL IMPLEMENTATION, NOTIFY THE CONTROLLER OF THE RELEASE
    ~Wrapper()
        { cout << "Wrapper dtor: " << id << "Welease Bwian! Ee, I mean, the wesouwce" << endl; }

    explicit Wrapper(Resource& r) : id(seq++), res(r)
      { cout << "Wrapper ctor: " << id << endl; }

    int getID() const { return id; }
private:
    int id;
    Resource& res;
};

class Controller
{
public:
    ~Controller() { for (auto r : allres) delete r; }
    Resource& GetResource();
private:
    // SIMPLIFIED. I'M USING Boost PTR CONTAINER
    vector<Resource *> allres;
};

// SIMPLIFIED. IT WOULD ACTUALLY GET A RESOURCE FROM THE POOL
Resource& Controller::GetResource()
{
    Resource* newres = new Resource();
    allres.push_back(newres);

    return *(newres);
}

// SIMULATE GLOBAL CONTEXT
Controller& GetController()
{
    static Controller f;
    return f;
}

void DoSomething(Wrapper& wr)
{
    cout << "DoSth INI" << endl;
    cout << wr.getID() << endl;
    cout << "DoSth END" << endl;
}

void DoSomethingElse()
{
    cout << "DoSthElse INI" << endl;
    Wrapper w(GetController().GetResource());
    DoSomething(w);
    cout << "DoSthElse END" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "main INI" << endl;
    cout << "Calling DoSthElse" << endl;
    DoSomethingElse();
    cout << "Called DoSthElse" << endl;
    cout << "main END" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Does your compiler support rvalue references? Then you can implement move semantics, to make it much, much simpler to work with noncopyable objects

Comment: Also, why bother exposing both the resource and the wrapper? All this does is allow more room for errors. Just expose a single RAII resource class. It shouldn't be up to the caller to wrap it. Why not just give the user a well-behaved RAII resource class?

Comment: @jalf: Yes, it does support it. You suggest I apply it to Resource? So that, when a resource is in use, I actually remove it from the container and move it to the wrapper/client? Of have I got it wrong? I've considered this, but it doesn't sound conceptually right; the ownership seems to be always in the Controller. As for exposing the resource, I know what you mean. I'm not entirely happy with it, and I may remove it as it progresses.

Comment: store your `Resource` objects in the controller, and return a `std::unique_ptr<Resource>` created with a custom deleter, for example. Then the user gets an object, passed by value, which he can do with as he pleases, and when it goes out of scope, it will invoke the custom deleter, which returns the resource to the pool

Comment: @jalf: So, on Resource use, Controller removes the Resource from the container, moves it to the unique_ptr and returns it by value to the user. On scope exit, unique_ptr's deleter hands the Resource back to the Controller, to be put back in the container. It's clean, but I don't like that the Controller is losing ownership during use. The Controller is responsible for the Resource's life-cycle management, even during use; as such, it seems to me it should retain ownership, i.e., the Resource should remain in the container at all times.

Comment: @jalf: Could you create an answer, so I can choose it, pls? Or should I do it? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAII is really about ownership. Who owns the object, and what do they need to do once they relinquish ownership of it?

The situation you're describing is that the resources are really *owned* by the Controller. The lifetimes of the resource objects are managed by the Controller.

Users of the resources effectively just "lock" the resource, marking it as "in use", but they don't take ownership of it. They don't affect its lifetime. (You could say that they own a lock, and then *that* is the resource that they need to manage)

So I'd suggest exposing something like a `std::unique_ptr<Resource>`, which is created with a custom deleter. (and which can be returned by value from the `controller.getResource()` call

Users can do with this `unique_ptr` what they like: it's not copyable, but it can be moved, and once it goes out of scope, it calls its custom deleter, which marks it as "unused" in the Controller, effectively returning it to the pool

That way you get to return an object by value, which is nice and simple to work with for the client, and you avoid exposing the "unwrapped" Resource objects at all: clients always get them wrapped in a `unique_ptr`, which eliminates a lot of potential errors.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your current code there isn't a way for the Controller to tell when a caller is done using a Wrapper/Resource. This means that when you get around to implementing Controller::GetResource there won't be any way for the controller to know whether it can return a previously created Resource or not.

Usually designs like this include a Controller::ReleaseResource that is called in the Wrapper destructor. This means that when the Wrapper is constructed it gets a resource, then when it is destructed it releases the resource. This is exactly RAII.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit when I said this is a simplified example. The actual code implements that. I've added a comment to `Wrapper::~Wrapper` to make it clear. Thanks for you help.